# Timeframe of MMA / HCY response to Vitamin B12 supplementation

Tags: blood-tests, micronutrients

What is the timeframe one can reasonably expect for elevated serum Methylmalonic Acid and Homocysteine levels to be normalized by supplementation (e.g. 250 μg daily cyanocobalamin), assuming functional Vitamin B12 deficiency is the context of the abnormal results?